# How can I create torrent files from transmission or deluge using GUI?

Tags: torrent-client

I can't find anywhere to 'create file' in Transmission/Deluge.

Answer (score 5):

With Transmission, it's pretty simple. Go to the *File* menu, click on *New*:

[image: Transmission New dialog screenshot]

Choose the file/folder you want to share in the `Source Folder/File` options and the location where the torrent file will be created in the `Save to` option. Add any trackers and comments, and click on *New*. You will be given an option to add the created torrent to Transmission.

In Deluge too, the process is simple. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, or, in the *File* menu, click on *Create Torrent*:
[image]

When you click on *Save*, you will be asked where to save the new torrent file.